# Proposal for questions about Digital modes, DMR, Echolink, and IRLP ect. to be added to the "What topics can I ask about here?" in the Help Center

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

I am thinking that it would be helpful for new Users of SE HR if questions about Digital modes, DMR, Echolink, and IRLP and other computer based Ham Radio Facets were added to the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) list in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of topics in the help center is not exhaustive, and is not in any way meant to be exhaustive. Note that it is preceded by *for example*. The idea is to give the person reading the help center article an idea what questions are likely to be welcomed by the community, and what is likely to be closed as off topic.

Specifically about your proposal,

- **digital modes** fall into the "modulation" bullet point; see the [digital](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital) tag, or more specific tags like [packet](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packet)
- at least **Echolink and IRLP** are techniques used widely in amateur radio so would fall into the "amateur radio" part of the site's scope; we have an [echolink](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echolink) tag

Hence, **I do not believe any help center article amendment is necessary.**